# Selective Merge and Deployment with Git

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a situation with Git Merging and Deployment.

We have the below Git Branching/Merging and Deployment setup (as is figure attached). Three teams are working of three parallel feature, and they merge they code to "test" (to deploy to TQA environment for testing). If the TQA passes, only those features move to Staging. And the releases happen on demand.

When a release happens, we need to merge the code from Staging into Master and Deploy to LIVE Environment from Master. The process was working smooth, as the feature were moving to LIVE in serial.
[image: desired-git-merge-deploy]
Now we have a situation where one feature needs to be fast forwarded to LIVE while the other two features are still in TQA and Staging. But when we merge the code from Staging to Master, it is merging all the three features and thus the feature not to be release also going to LIVE.

How can we avoid this situation. Attached figure explains the desired behavior. We are using VSTS Git.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge just the feature branch into master rather than merging all of the staging branch.

Comment: Would the `git cherry-pick` not help here? Will this be not a right approach ?

Comment: @spideringweb `git cherry-pick` copies the changes of one commit and creates a new commit with the exact same changes. This causes the same changes to appear more than once in the history of your repo. The main problem that arises is that you will have merge conflicts when you eventually decide to merge the staging branch which also has those same changes.

Comment: I have similar situation. But earlier we used to do Tags. Where in we create multiple tags that can be merged with single or multiple checkins from single to various branches. But treated as a bunch and can go together or separately. IS there similar or other way to get this done without merging everything and anything in stage to master?

Comment: @WPFKK Please post a new question by clicking the Ask Question button at the top right. Then you can write your question with enough detail so that someone that wants to help can understand what your exact situation is. Feel free to include a link to this question in your own question if it is appropriate.